# Click event only on specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a page with product images on it and above each image is a 'more info' button. When clicked there is an overlay over the image with more information. 
The html looks something like this:

```
<div class=“products_overlay overlay_test”>
  <div class=“products_overlay_info”>
    <div class=“product_more_info”>
        <span>More Info</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class=“hover_text”>
    <li class=“product_less_info”><span>Less Info</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now once the overlay is visible there's another button which says 'less info' and once clicked it hides the overlay with the extra information. This is the jQuery for it:

```
$j('.product_more_info').on('click', function(){
$j('.product_less_info').show();
$j('.product_more_info').hide();


});

$j('.product_less_info').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$j('.product_more_info').show();
$j('.product_less_info').hide();
});
```

This works, however my problem is that it's a list of products/images so when the user click 'more info' and it hides that div it hides the div for all the products/images , not just the one the user clicked on.
I've tried using `.next` but with no luck.

```
$j('.product_more_info').on('click', function(){
    $j(this).next('.product_less_info').show();
    $j(this).next('.product_more_info').hide();

});
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You just need to show and hide the div as you are doing for `product_less info` and `product_more_info`.

Comment: Why are you putting the less info button in a list outside of your regular product images construct? And how much sense does a list with one entry make?

Comment: The way your demo works, you should also have the problem that clicking on "more info" opens the info layer on all images, not just on the one the user clicked, right?

Comment: @connexo I have to do this due to the layout of the page and the list doesn't just have one entry in it- I just didn't include the rest of the li to shorten the code and as there was no need for them to explain the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$j('.product_more_info').on('click', function(){
    $j('.product_less_info', $j(this).parents('.products_overlay')).show();
    $j(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This lacks any explanation of how this solves the given problem.

Comment: also it is not optimized solution as `.parents()` will go up to the document root, which is not neccessary

Comment: @pwolaq :  .parents()  the elements are returned in order from the closest parent to the outer ones. see here https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: I know how it works, I just said that you should use `closest` as you want only first parent, there is no point in getting all of them

Answer (score 2):

easiest way to do it is to access common ancestor using `.closest(selector)` - in this case it is `.products_overlay`

```
$j('.product_more_info').on('click', function(){
    $j(this).closest('.products_overlay').find('.product_less_info').show();
    $j(this).hide();
});
```

you can also achieve this calling `.parent()` two times:

```
$j('.product_more_info').on('click', function(){
    $j(this).parent().parent().find('.product_less_info').show();
    $j(this).hide();
});
```

but `.closest(selector)` in this case is more reliable as you may change your html structure in the future a bit